# Do I need a Brazil transit visa

Tags: saudi-citizens

I have flight on Qatar airlines from Doha to International Sao Paulo on 5th of Jan Terminal 3 . I will arrive to San Paulo on 5th Jan at  16:50 and then layover 13 hours then continuing on LAN Airlines in 6th Jan at 6:40 Terminal 2. Do I need to Go thru immigration Brazil? Thanks

Comment: Was this booked as a single ticket, or self-transfer?

Comment: My flight way from Doha to Santiago in chile however I will layover 13 hours in san Paulo GUR international airport. My citizenship is Saudi. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear on the maps at the link below, but I'm quite sure, and this appears to be supported by the maps, that there is an airside connection between Terminal 2 and Terminal 3.

https://www.gru.com.br/en/passenger/discover-gru/airport-maps/

So, *if* you bought your journey as one ticket, and you do not need to collect your luggage, you *should* not have to go through immigration to get to your connecting flight.

That said, you really should check with the issuing airline.

Edit: I arrived at GRU Terminal 3 yesterday (30/11/2021). There is a connection with Terminal 2, airside. It was guarded, but seemed in operation.

Comment: The answer above is true only if the airport remains open overnight...and not all airports do. The [GUR airport website](https://www.gru.com.br/en/) does not reveal what hours the airport is open. [Sleeping in Airports](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/guides/sao-paulo-guarulhos-airport-guide.htm) states that GUR is open 24 hrs/day, and while it says there's a T2-T3 walkway does not specify that the walkway is airside.

Comment: From personal experience, I'm quite confident the airport stays open overnight.

Comment: I assume your edit is referring to an occurrence on 30/ **11** /2021, as 30/ **12** /2021 hasn't yet arrived.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica: Let's pretend it does.